# Image moves with progress in Progress Bar android

Tags: android

I want to make a layout like the highlighted red rectangle in the image given below.An image/icon would appear with the progress of the progress bar. Is it possible to do this in android? because I cant find any tutorials for this.
[Flight status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbAjE.jpg)

Comment: use seek bar and make it custom

Answer (score 1):

Try this way it will work

```
<com.bq.markerseekbar.MarkerSeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:max="100"
        app:markerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:markerTextAppearance="@style/MarkerCustomTextStyle"
        app:markerTextColor="#ffffff" />
```

https://github.com/bq/MarkerSeekBar

https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar

https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom style of specific color for your seekbar from the following site:-

http://android-holo-colors.com/

It will create a style.xml file and some images in drawable folder

> eg:-thumb image, seekbar image etc.

And, then you can replace images you want in drawable folder  with your own images.

> eg:- you can replace the thumb image with your air-plane thumb image.

Finally, apply the style in Seekbar.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with -

You just need to set thumb that is your flight image `.png`
All you need to do is - 

1) get you `drawable` from `drawable` diretory -

```
Drawable thumb = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.myThumb );
```

2) set it to your seekbar -

```
mSeekbar.setThumb(thumb);
```

**Ps, Leave some padding while designing your `.png` as there is space available around your flight icon.**